# Probability and combinatorics on tetahedron faces.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let it be a tetrahedron with the numbers $1$,$2$,$3$ and $4$ on its faces.The tetrahedron is launch $3$ times. Each time, the number that stays face down is registered.

$1$)In total how many possible ways there are to registered the $3$ launches?

As there are $4$ numbers to $3$ launches(positions), the order matters and each number can repeats itself. I used a permutation with replacement: $4^3=64$

$2$)How many possible ways there are to the number $1$ never face down?

In this case I reduced the sample set to $\{2,3,4 \}$, and made the same as before. But this time there are $3$ numbers to $3$ launchs: $3^3=27$

$3$)How many possible ways there are to the number $1$ appears only $1$ time face down?

There are $3$ ways for number $1$ can be put on the $3$ launches. For the $2$ left there is $\{2,3,4 \}$.So I made a permutation with replacement: $3 \cdot 3^2=27$

$4$)How many possible ways there are to the number $1$ appears exactly $2$ times face down?

First I made a combination: $C(3,2)$ to find the number of ways that the pair of $1$'s can be put in the $3$ launchs.Then I multiplied by $3$, that is $ \{2,3,4 \}$ : $C(3,2) \cdot 3=9$.

Is this correct?
Thank you very much, you(plural)have been very helpful.

Comment: In (3), you mean $3 \cdot 3^2=27$.

Comment: There is also $1$ way the number $1$ appears three times face down, and the fact that $27+27+9+1=64$ should be encouraging.

Comment: That sounds right.  As a check, you should argue that $1$ can appear on the bottom on no rolls, one roll, two rolls, or three rolls (there are no other possibilities), and you have worked out the number of ways that $1$ never appears, appears once, and appears twice for a total of $27 + 27 + 9 = 63$ of the $64$ occurrences. The remaining possibility is that of $1$ on all three rolls, right?  Of course, all the numbers adding up doesn't _guarantee_ that they are correct, but if they _don't_ add up, that suggests that the work and the argument needs to be checked.

Comment: @Dilip You should make that an answer.

Comment: The work was nicely done.

Comment: João, on this site, people are allowed, in fact encouraged, to post their own answers to problems, and to accept them too.  So why don't you post your work as an answer (after a little clean-up of the write-up you already have, and possibly incorporating the suggestions for a check that Henry and I suggested)? As André Nicolas and Thanassis said, the work was nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct, well done.

An alternate/complimentary way to answer the last question:

If two throws are '1' then we have only one throw which is not '1'. There are 3 ways for the not-'1' throw to be put down. And not-'1' has 3 cases as you said: $\{2,3,4\}$. So again $3 \cdot 3 = 9$

This might make you notice that in general: $_NC_1 = \space _NC_{N-1} = N$. In other words I can choose $1$ item from $N$ items in $N$ different ways, or complimentary (and exactly equivalently) I can choose $N-1$ items from $N$ items. So if we are throwing the tetrahedron $N$ times you could either ask: 1) how many ways to roll '1' (N-1) times?, or 2) how many ways to roll not-'1' one time? It's the same question isn't it? And combinatorics rightly produces the same answer to both of them.

More generally $_NC_i = \space _NC_{N-i}$. You might already know that, but maybe now you can get some more insight into it.

Can you give the general solution to you problem? That is, let's say we have a set of $N$ numbers (a dice of $N$ sides) and we throw it $M$ times. How many possible ways exist to get the same number $K$ times?